# Reverse for 'temp1' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['userinput/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I just want to retrieve data dynamically.

**urls.py**

I think there is something error in views.py or urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name='home'),
    path("userinput/", views.template, name='template'),
    path("userinput/<int:id>/", views.temp1, name='temp1'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from home.models import UserDetail

# Create your views here.

def template(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        nm     = request.POST['name']
        eml    = request.POST['email']
        adrs   = request.POST['address']
        

        data = UserDetail(name=nm, email=eml, address=adrs)
        data.save()

    return render(request, 'template.html')

def temp1(request, id):
    userdetail = UserDetail.objects.get(pk=id) 
    return render(request, 'temp1.html', {'userdetail':userdetail})
```

**template.html**

I think my error is related to views.py or in template.html file

```
{% load static %}

    
{% block css_files %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '' %}">
{% endblock  %}

{% block content %}



<form id="resume-form" action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Enter your details</h1>
    <div class="generate">
        <div class="per"> 
        <h2>Personal details</h2>

            <div class="a">
                <label for="namefields">Your Name</label><br>
                <input type="text" class="" id="namefields" placeholder="Enter here" name="name">
            </div>

            <div class="a">
                <label for="emailfield">Your Email</label><br>
                <input type="email" class="" id="emailfield" placeholder="Enter here" name="email">
            </div>

            <div class="a">
                <label for="addressfield">Your Address</label><br>
                <textarea id="addressfield" placeholder="Enter here" rows="3" cols="" name="address"></textarea>
            </div>          
           
    <div class="generatebtn">
        <a href="{% url 'temp1' userdetail.id %}"><button type="Submit">Submit</button></a>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

can anyone say why it shows "NoReverseMatch at /userinput/" what it means??????
I am new to Django.

Comment: Your template has no `userdetail` item in the context.

Comment: so, how can I do that???